# SQL - How to achieve scoring and matching for categories?

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to achieve scoring and matching in MySQL. I have a table that has 3 level's of category level1 (ultimate parent), level2 (parent) and level3(child).
I am trying to assign a score for each new data category that I receive from outside and assign it to a particular category ID from my table `score += r.score * weight`

```
+----+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
| ID | LEVEL1                             | LEVEL2                      | LEVEL3             |
+----+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
| 1  |  Arts and Entertainment Businesses |  Casinos                    |  NULL              |
| 1  |  Arts and Entertainment Businesses |  Performing Arts Businesses |  Radio Stations    |
| 2  |  Auto Sales Businesses             |  Motorcycle Dealers         |  Motorcycle Parts  |
| 2  |  Auto Sales Businesses             |  RVs and Motor Home Dealers |  NULL              |
| 2  |  Auto Sales Businesses             |  Car Dealers                |  Used Cars Dealers |
| 3  |  Bars and Lounges                  |  Pubs and Dive Bars         |  Pubs              |
| 3  |  Bars and Lounges                  |  Wine Bars                  |  NULL              |
| 4  |  Restaurants                       |  American Restaurants       |  Barbeque          |
+----+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
```

The above is my master table which has the category.

**What I am trying to do:**

```
If input = 'Radio',
   Then match to LEVEL3 'Radio Station' with score less than 1.0
If LEVEL3 is NULL, Move up to LEVEL2
   Then Match to LEVEL2 
IF LEVEL2 is NULL, Move up to LEVEl1
   Then Match to LEVEL1

scores: 0.0(No Match) to 1.00 (Exact match)
        0.8 - 0.99 (Very good Match)
```

I am trying to calculate the proximity score for all the input variables and then assign them the ID. If No data in level3 and level2, then there is a row for each LEVEL1 with LEVEL2 and LEVEL3 as `Other`, which will be lowest score match.

I am really trying to wrap this is SQL without going to Python ML/AI and over engineer it. (if it's impossible in SQL then I will goto Python)
Any thoughts would be helpful.

**Expected Result:**

```
Input = Used Cars
Output = [ID: 2 ,LEVEL1 : Auto Sales Business]
```

**Please see:** I understand that this might not exactly fall technical issue / code error. I do understand stackoverflow rules of not posting a discussion and focus on getting an answer. Any pointers / SQL code / Python script will be of great help to me. Thanks.

Comment: add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Added the expected result. The data sample is the table (subset of the major table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one option in tsql using character length to assign the score.-

```
DECLARE @imput varchar(300) = 'Radio';

WITH Data AS (
SELECT  1  as id,  'Arts and Entertainment Businesses' AS Level1,  'Casinos'                    AS Level2,  NULL               AS Level3 Union
SELECT  1  as id,  'Arts and Entertainment Businesses' AS Level1,  'Performing Arts Businesses' AS Level2,  'Radio Stations'   AS Level3 Union
SELECT  2  as id,  'Auto Sales Businesses'             AS Level1,  'Motorcycle Dealers'         AS Level2,  'Motorcycle Parts' AS Level3 Union
SELECT  2  as id,  'Auto Sales Businesses'             AS Level1,  'RVs and Motor Home Dealers' AS Level2,  NULL               AS Level3 Union
SELECT  2  as id,  'Auto Sales Businesses'             AS Level1,  'Car Dealers'                AS Level2,  'Used Cars Dealers'AS Level3 Union
SELECT  3  as id,  'Bars and Lounges'                  AS Level1,  'Pubs and Dive Bars'         AS Level2,  'Pubs'             AS Level3 Union
SELECT  3  as id,  'Bars and Lounges'                  AS Level1,  'Wine Bars'                  AS Level2,  NULL               AS Level3 Union
SELECT  4  as id,  'Restaurants'                       AS Level1,  'American Restaurants'       AS Level2,  'Barbeque'         AS Level3 
)

SELECT * 
    ,CAST(Len(@imput) AS numeric(18,2))/Len(COALESCE(Level3,Level2,Level1)) AS Score 
FROM data
WHERE COALESCE(Level3,Level2,Level1) LIKE '%'+ @imput + '%'
```

Comment: Thank you, I am using this as my starting point